# How to install R library "ggpubr" in a Docker image?

Tags: r, linux, docker, ggpubr

I tried to install the R library `ggpubr` in a docker image. I pulled the r-base:3.6.3 and the following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:3.6.3
COPY . /usr/local/src/myscripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/myscripts
RUN Rscript Rinstall_packages.R
```

and here is my Rinstall_packages.R file:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("reshape")
install.packages("ggpubr")
install.packages("stringr")
```

each time I got the output like this:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/car’
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘rstatix’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstatix’
ERROR: dependency ‘rstatix’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggpubr’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp0tYFyC/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("ggpubr") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("ggpubr") :
  installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("ggpubr") :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("ggpubr") :
  installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("ggpubr") :
  installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to install the library in batch mode:

```
docker run -ti --rm r-base:3.6.3 bash
apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
R
>install.packages("ggpubr")
```

It works. However, after I exited the bash, I still can not use the library.

Is there anyone can help me to install this lib?

Comment: Try with `dependencies = TRUE` in `install.packages`.  Also, change the `repos` if necessary

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make change to a container (ie a running image) those are made in a **temporary** layer that do not persist after the container is stopped and removed. You have to change the image so that when you start the container everything is available. So you have to change the `Dockerfile`.

You did add the system library `libcurl4-openssl-dev` do make things work so add it to your `Dockerfile` on the second line.

```
FROM r-base:3.6.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
COPY . /usr/local/src/myscripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/myscripts
RUN Rscript Rinstall_packages.R
```

Bear also in mind that calling `Rscript` does not start `R` the same way you start an interactive `R` (options, preloaded libraries could be different)

I second @akrun to be more explicit for parameters to avoid those caveats.

Comment: Cool. Could you accept the answer so as others can know that it solved your question.